# Compute confidence intervals in presto

Tags: presto

I'm looking for a handy query to compute confidence intervals of a single column in presto.  Is it possible to do this without a nested query?

Comment: can you share what exactly do you want to compute? mean, std. deviation etc? Also, would be helpful to see your nested query to understand a better question.